# Open source search engines : alternatives to Lucene

Tags: search, open-source, lucene, full-text-search, search-engine

Currently we are using Lucene for our search engine, but we want to look at some alternatives. I have looked at several on the net but seems like a lot of them are out of date or the development stopped. That is why I want to ask if you guys know any good open-source alternatives to Lucene that are still in development?

Kind regards,

Merlijn

Answer (score 3):

Try Sphinx search http://sphinxsearch.com/. It is used by many NLP researchers.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for an open source and Java based alternative, then you could try [Terreir](http://terrier.org/%20Terrier). Note that Terrier targets academia.

If the language is not an issue, then you could look at [Xapian](http://xapian.org/%20Xapian). I found its community quite active, and it has participated in Google Summer of Code several times.

Otherwise, you could try Whoosh, a python based search library.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions. Will certainly take a look at them.  We're looking for java based alternatives btw

Answer (score 0):

[FastcatSearch](https://github.com/fastcatgroup/fastcatsearch) is also open source and java based alternative.

Lucene is a IR library as already you know, Solr is a search server, and FastcatSearch is a counterpart of Solr.

It provides web-based manager, so that you can set up configs easily.